# How to use auth token in Cortana Connected account scenario with graph api sdk

Tags: botframework, microsoft-graph-api, cortana-skills-kit

I am trying to follow the Cortana connected account example provided [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cortana-Skills-Samples-Build-2017/tree/master/P4063/birthday-bot-csharp). The default example uses live api which is working fine; however, I wanted to use Graph api sdk. Trying to use the same auth token (which is sent by Cortana as one of the entities) with Graph api is giving this error:

```
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: InvalidAuthenticationToken 
Message: CompactToken parsing failed with error code: -2147184118
```

The relevant code is:
`var graphserviceClient = new GraphServiceClient(new AzureAuthenticationProvider(authAccessToken));`

The AzureAuthenticationProvider class is:

```
public  class AzureAuthenticationProvider : IAuthenticationProvider
{
    string _accessToken;
    public AzureAuthenticationProvider(string accessToken)
    {
        _accessToken = accessToken;
    }

    public async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + _accessToken);
    }
}
```

How can I use the auth token sent by Cortana to my bot to perform Graph queries using the Graph Sdk?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get a token for graph resource from Cortana, the Token URL in Connected Account should have a query parameter called `resource=https://graph.microsoft.com/` Also, to verify the validity of the token, try decoding it using JWT.io. You should be able to see graph as the audience in your token.